# Using three20 to display a table view with styled text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, three20

I'm trying to get my head around three20. It's a big beast, but I want it to do just a small thing - display a table view with styled text within the cells.

How would I create and show such a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom Cells and add textfield as per your style to its contentview